# Any way to have a real-time preview of AVMutableComposition? If no, how does Final Cut Pro does it?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, finalcut

is it possible to have a real-time preview of `AVMutableComposition` which has some `layer instructions` applied to its assets?

The only class I found that connects `AVMutableComposition` with `AVVideoComposition (holding instructions)` is `AVExportSession`. Does it mean I must export it first to play a preview?

If so, how does apps like `Final Cut Pro` serve real-time preview when I edit part of the video. Do they cut the whole video into multiple chunks, export what has changed and keep change of everything else?

This sounds like a difficult problem - is there any library that would help in cutting video into small chunks to export and keeping an eye on cache invalidation?

Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real time preview with `AVMutableComposition` , they may create a time slot for every change and manage it's visibility when you change the slider below

Comment: Do you think they're using AVExportSession or is there some lower-level API that gives more control over the process?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant but you can always extract each frame from the video, manipulate it accordingly then render it to the screen.

If its from `AVCaptureSession` you can get `CMSampleBuffer` from the callbacks, if it's a file I think `AVReader` is your best bet then you can use either `CoreImage` or `Metal` to manipulate the frames and render them in real-time.

Comment: Thanks Siya. I'm no longer working on this problem but I'll give it a try one day.